# When is "to be" used in passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

> This is carried out according to the course and wale quality of the fabric to be knitted by the knitting machine.

We could write **fabric is knitted/fabric will be knitted/fabric can be knitted**. But here, in the sentence stated above, **fabric to be knitted** has been used? Would anybody like to tell me when **to be+past participle** is used instead of **auxiliary verbs+past participle**?

Comment: **To be** ***IS*** an auxiliary verb when it is not the main verb of the verb phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Fabric "to be knitted" is a relatively stylistically unusual way to avoid using a longer relative clause.  It is equivalent to saying "The fabric which will be knitted" or "The fabric that will be knitted".  It is a little shorter as written, but it sounds archaic or a little strange if used in an informal setting.

Answer (score 1):

"the fabric to be knitted" is "fabric" + to-infinitive passive and has the meaning of "the fabric that is to be knitted".

Comment: I think, "that is to be knitted" equals to "that will be knitted". Am I right?

Comment: @NazmulHassan No, they aren't. The first one focus on a present action. The second focus on an action that someone will do in the future.

Comment: Actually, @Subjunctive you are incorrect. *to be* plus *past participle* is a way to refer to **future time**. So, yes, Nazmul, you are right, as is this answer  *The book to be read* is *the book that will be read*. See the nice answer by **Noah**.